# Poles of $\frac{\cos(z) - 1}{e^z - 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to check in which points function $$f(z) := \frac{\cos(z) - 1}{e^z - 1}$$ has poles.

The only candidate for pole in this example is for $z = 0$, since that's the only point that function is not defined in. However, since for all $n \in \mathbb N$ we see that

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow0}f(z) = \lim_{z \rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(z) - 1}{e^{z} - 1}z^n = 0$$

And for me its sufficient to say that this function does not have pole anywhere. Am I correct saying so?

**Expanding in Taylor series**

As suggested in answers, to see where the poles are, I can use taylor expansion:

$$\frac{\cos(z) - 1}{e^z - 1} = \frac{\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n)!}-1}{\sum_{n= 0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!} - 1} = \frac{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n)!}}{\sum_{n= 1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}} =$$
$$= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n z^n \frac{n!}{(2n)!}$$

But now here the smallest power is $1$, so the coefficient related to that one is pole:

$$(-1)^1 \cdot \frac 1 1 = -1$$

But it's different what you said in answers (that pole is in $2\pi i n$). Where do I have a mistake?

Comment: Are you claiming that $f$ *is* defined at $2\pi i$?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** The mapping $z\mapsto \frac{\cos (z)-1}{e^{z}-1}$ has simple pole at $z=2i n\pi$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $z\not=0$. This can be seen using Taylor series.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I expanded function into Taylor series. Could you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

Recall a pole of $f$ is a zero of $1/f$.

$$1/f(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{\cos z -1}=\frac{e^z-1}{\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz}) -1}.$$

The candidates for poles of $f$ are $2\pi i n,n\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$; verify these are zeros of $1/f$.