# Poles of $\frac{cos(z) - 1}{e^z - 1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to check in which points function $$f(z) := \frac{\cos(z) - 1}{e^z - 1}$$ has poles. To do so I'm going to expand this function into Laurent series. We know that if we have Laurent series in form of :

$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty a_n(z - z_0)^n = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_{-n}(z - z_0)^{-n} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n(z - z_0)^n$$

then we have pole with rank $m$ when $a_{-m} \neq 0$ and $a_{k} = 0$ for $k < -m$.

But if we expand it:

$$\frac{\cos(z) - 1}{e^z - 1} = \frac{\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!} - 1}{\sum_{n =0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}-1} = \frac{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!}}{\sum_{n =1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}}=$$
$$=\sum_{n = 1}^\infty(-1)^nz^n\frac{n!}{(2n)!}$$

So we only have regular part of Laurent series, so there is no expression with $a_{-m}$ so I cannot judge there the pole is. However, the poles should be in points $2\pi i n$. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You asked an [identical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4386172/poles-of-frac-cosz-1ez-1) two days ago. Voting to close.

Comment: But there is no answer there...I updated my question there because I didn't understand the answers and no one reacted. That's the reason I asked it one more time.

Comment: There are already two answers. If you want to attract more attention, place a bounty on the question.